# location.state becomes null when I set it for the second time

Tags: reactjs

I have a sig-in sign-up scenario in my website, in which when a user lands in page1, it should be singed-in, so it would redirected to sign-in page by a command like below in page1.js

```
history.push({
       pathname: '/login-page',
       state: { from: '/page1' }
   });
```

Obviously, if the user has not signed-up yet, it would again redicred to sign-up page from sig-in page by a command which retrieve pathname from above state.from

Now in sign-up page the user could return back to sign-in page

```
history.push({
       pathname: '/login-page',
       state: { from: from }
   });
```

which again from retrvied from state.from, the problem is that all these states wol fine till sign-up page, but when the user land in sign-in page the location.state is always undefined while I have used explicitly above command with the path name set to '/login-page'. Does anyone have any clue why this happens?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, when the user **lands** on a route, the state is always null.

Comment: yes, for the second time, not first time, when I hit the login page the state is null.   page1 --> login (state is fine) --> signup (state is fine) --> login (state becomes null)

Comment: Maybe it's because the state is "persist per location". Similar to the case described in the section starts with `If the same component is used as the child of multiple <Route>s` - https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route. I'm not sure what's the solution though.